# Min Max Comma Separated Range In Sql Server with Different Ranges in One Cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have write  this query using Stuff to generate ranges but there is aproblem in this due to group on time of entry  if same time entered different range then it can't find the min max of range

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST2.Center_Code
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT ' , ' + ST1.Ranges
            FROM (
                SELECT Center_Code
                    ,CAST(MIN(CONVERT(BIGINT, Starting_No)) AS VARCHAR(9)) + '-' + CAST(MAX(CONVERT(BIGINT, Starting_No)) AS VARCHAR(9)) Ranges
                FROM AwardSheet_Record
                GROUP BY Center_Code
                    ,LEFT(Despatch_Time, 8)
                ) ST1
            WHERE ST1.Center_Code = ST2.Center_Code
            ORDER BY ST1.Center_Code
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '') Center_Range
FROM AwardSheet_Record ST2
WHERE ST2.Center_Code IS NOT NULL
```

In table record is like this

```
CenterCode   starting    time
  123           1       2:30
  123           2       2:30
  123           3       2:30
  14            6       2:33
  14            7       2:33
  14            8       2:33
  123           9       2:35
  123           10      2:35
  14            11      2:38
  14            12      2:38
  14            13      2:38
```

required Range is   for center 123  1-2,8-10 and for center 14 6-8,11-13

Comment: @Y.B Condsider record is like this                                                            CenterCode   starting 
  123                  1       
  123                  2       
  123                  3       
  14                    6       
  14                    7       
  14                    8       
  123                  9       
  123                 10      
  14                   11      
  14                   12      
  14                   13

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in stages:

```
With AwardSheet_Record As (
    Select CenterCode, starting, cast(Time as Time) As Time
    From (Values 
        ((123 ),(1 ),('2:30')),
        ((123 ),(2 ),('2:30')),
        ((123 ),(3 ),('2:30')),
        ((14  ),(6 ),('2:33')),
        ((14  ),(7 ),('2:33')),
        ((14  ),(8 ),('2:33')),
        ((123 ),(9 ),('2:35')),
        ((123 ),(10),('2:35')),
        ((14  ),(11),('2:38')),
        ((14  ),(12),('2:38')),
        ((14  ),(13),('2:38'))
    ) a (CenterCode, starting, Time)
), AwardSheet_Intervals As (
    Select CenterCode, Time, Cast(Min(starting) As Varchar) + ' - ' + Cast(Max(starting) As Varchar) As Interval
    From AwardSheet_Record
    Group By CenterCode, Time
)
Select CenterCode,
  STUFF((
    Select ', ' + Interval
    From AwardSheet_Intervals
    Where CenterCode = Ref.CenterCode --< Apply GROUP BY filtering here
    Order By Time
    For XML PATH (''), TYPE
  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') As [Range] --< XML trick to combine values in a comma-separated string
From AwardSheet_Intervals Ref
Group By CenterCode;
```

---

```
CenterCode  Range
----------  --------------
        14  6 - 8, 11 - 13
       123  1 - 3, 9 - 10
```

Comment: My old query is work fine But I do not want to group on time for min, max  but only on center code  because time will be same if many users entered different ranges for one center at a time